# Keeping user state in memory

Tags: android

I have an app with a login process, each time the user logs in I store the information in a LoginHolder class like this:

```
private static final java.lang.String TAG = tag(LoginHolder.class);
private static LoginHolder INSTANCE;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;


private LoginDetails mLoginDetails;
private UserInfo mUserInfo;

private LoginHolder(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    mSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
}

public synchronized static LoginHolder instance(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new LoginHolder(prefs);
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public LoginDetails getLoggedUser() {
    return mLoginDetails;
}

@DebugLog
public void setLoggedUser(@NonNull LoginDetails loginDetails) {
    this.mLoginDetails = loginDetails;
}



@DebugLog
void setUserInfo(@NonNull UserInfo userInfo) {
    mUserInfo = userInfo;
}

public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
    return mUserInfo;
}
```

}

As you can see this is a Singleton class that I am injecting using Dagger.

Now I have two activities, one is activity A and second is activity B. A launches activity B (and conceptually is its parent, sort of a master-detail relationship). Now when a crash happens at B, then the A activity is recreated. I have checked with logging and in fact the whole app is recreated (up to the Application object). This causes the singleton to go away and thus the user info as well.

So far I could only reproduce it in this case but I fear this might happen unexpectedly in other cases as well (any ideas?)

How can I preserve this information in memory at all times (until the user logs out of course)?

Comment: use simple SHaredPreference.

Comment: "How is this possible?" -- since `mUserInfo` is never assigned a value, it will always be `null`. Unless, of course, you are not showing all your `LoginHelper` code here. In that case, we cannot really advise you, as we have no idea what your code is that references and manipulates `mUserInfo`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thats right, I didnt post the whole code, I just edited it to reflect the getters & setters

Comment: In fact, all the screens in my app depend on this class, I just set it up at the begining on the login screen, then the remaining screens can obtain the info through this Singleton class.

Comment: "How can I preserve this information in memory at all times" -- you can't, as eventually your process will be terminated. "when the activity is recreated" -- try a more conventional re-creation approach, such as rotating the screen.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tested that and it works. I narrowed the problem a bit and edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I preserve this information in memory at all times?**

Create an application class than extends `android.app.Application` and define LoginDetails inside that class.

In this case, this value will stay in memory fore the whole app lifecycle.

Example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   private static MyApplication instance;
   private LoginDetails loginDetails;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       instance = this;
   }

   public static LoginDetails getLoginDetails() {
       return instance.loginDetails;
   }
   public static void setLoginDetails(LoginDetails loginDetails) {
       instance.loginDetails = loginDetails;
   }
}
```

And in your manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    .....
</application>
```

Comment: This is what I am doing, but Appliction object is also recreated. Check my updated question.

Comment: You need then to persist this data. Using SharedPreferences is an option.